# Create RDS database using ANSIBLE

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, boto3, boto

I was wondering if anyone could help me? I'm trying to provision a database rds using ansible.
I have created this and when I tried to execute nothing happens:

```yaml
- name: create-rds-intance
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts : false

  tasks:
    - name: provision oracle rds intance
      rds:
        command: create
        region: us-west-1
        instance_name: my-db
        db_engine: oracle-se
        size: "10"
        instance_type: db.m3.xlarge
        username: root
        password: "password"
        tags:
          environment: staging
```

When I execute, I have nothing, and I don't know how to investigate what is going on...

```
$ ansible-playbook  first-playbook-1.yml 
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [create-rds-intance] **************************************************************************************************************

TASK [provision oracle rds intance] ****************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to create instance: "}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Does anyone has a very simple example that works?
Also, I was wondering if it is possible to execute an SQL script right after rds instance is created?

Regards,

Comment: What version of ansible are you running?

Comment: Hello, 

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.10.3
  config file = None
  configured module search path = [u'/home/.../.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.18 (default, Aug 27 2020, 21:22:52) [GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/aws/rds_module.html) for the `rds` module suggests using the `rds_instance` instead:

> - Please use boto3 based [community.aws.rds_instance](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/rds_instance_module.html) instead.

Also you might be missing some of the required parameters. I have used the `rds_instance` module to create and it worked with below parameters:

```yaml
- name: create RDS instance
  rds_instance:
    allocated_storage: 50
    availability_zone: "myaz"
    aws_access_key: "aws_access_key_id"
    aws_secret_key: "aws_secret_access_key"
    db_instance_class: "db.m5.xlarge"
    db_instance_identifier: "my-test-rds"
    db_name: "tdb"
    db_parameter_group_name: "my-oracle-param"
    db_subnet_group_name: "my-subnet"
    engine: "oracle-ee"
    engine_version: "12.1.0.2.v19"
    license_model: "bring-your-own-license"
    master_user_password: "secret"
    master_username: "dbmaster"
    max_allocated_storage: 100
    option_group_name: "my-oracle-og"
    port: "1521"
    region: "us-west-1"
    state: "present"
    storage_type: "gp2"
    vpc_security_group_ids: "sg-123456"
```

If you don't want to keep the AWS credentials (access key, secret key) in the playbook, you can load them from Vault or through environment variables.

**Update**

For the second question: There is no straight forward method to run SQL commands. I had to setup [Oracle instantclient](https://www.oracle.com/in/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html) soon after the RDS creation to do database import, schema creation kind of stuff using the `sqlplus` command line.

At the very minimum, we need:

- Instant client basic (lite) package
- SQLPlus package

Comment: Hello, 

Thank you for this. I will try again with rds_instance. 
And about my second question, do you know if I can execute an SQL script immediately after creating the instance? I mean in the same ansible script?

Comment: Hello, 

Can you tell me how I can inside the same ansible playbook reference that database and install the instant client? I'm quite new to ansible and everything is kind of new to me.

Comment: The module returns the `endpoint`. We can `register` the same in a variable and use it for further connections. Please see the **Return Codes** section of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: "Load SQL script into a variable"
  set_fact:
    migration_sql: "{{ lookup('file', 'conf/migration.sql') }}"
- name: was main config file found
  debug: var=migration_sql

- name: "Execute script from variable"
  command: "psql {{ db_name }} -c {{ migration_sql }}"
  become_user: postgres
  register: sql_response_variable
- name: sql response code
  debug: var=sql_response_variable
```